# Maximum number of simple paths from $s$ to $t$

Tags: graph-theory

In the given diagram below the only possible moves are E, NE or SE. I need to find the total number of simple paths (in which no vertex repeats) from $s$ to $t$.

One such path is shown by arrow.
[image: graph]

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Did you mean, E, NE, SE?

Comment: Note that with the restriction to "only possible moves" east, northeast, and southeast, the "no vertex repeats" condition is automatically satisfied.  An elaborate way to compute the number of paths involves taking powers of the adjacency matrix for this directed graph.  Counting by hand is easier if you break down cases in one way or another, e.g. by starting with the shortest possible path from $s$ to $t$ and lengthening it, or by picking intermediate points to go through or avoid.

Comment: Yes, I actually meant E. Thanks for rectifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_0,v_1,\ldots$ be the vertices on the bottom row, from left to right, so $v_0=s$ and $v_4=t$.
Let $w_0,w_1,\ldots$ be the vertices on the second row.

Let $V_n$ be the number of paths to $v_n$ and $W_n$ the number of paths to $w_n$.
We are looking for $V_n$, or, more specific, for $V_4$.

We have initial conditions $V_0=W_0=1$
and recursive relations $V_n=V_{n-1}+W_{n-1}$ and $W_n=2W_{n-1}+V_n$ for $n>1$.
Substituting $W_{n-1}=V_n-V_{n-1}$ into the second relation gives us
$V_{n+1}-V_n=2V_n-2V_{n-1}+V_n$ or $V_{n+1}=4V_n-2V_{n-1}$.

This is a standard homogeneous linear recurrence.
Its characteristic equation is $x^2-4x+2=0$, so the characteristic roots are $2\pm\sqrt2$,
which provides us with the general solution $V_n=A(2+\sqrt2)^n+B(2-\sqrt2)^n$.

The initial condition $V_0=1$ yields $A+B=1$.
You can obtain $V_1=2$ either by inspection or by using the original recursive relations.
This yields $A(2+\sqrt2)+B(2-\sqrt2)=2$, so we find $A=B=\frac12$.

The general solution becomes $V_n=\frac{(2+\sqrt2)^n+(2-\sqrt2)^n}2$.
Use the binomial formula to write this as $V_n=\sum_{k\mbox{ even,}k=0}^n\binom nk2^{n-\frac k2}$.

The specific answer to this question then becomes $V_4=\binom402^4+\binom422^3+\binom442^2=
16+48+4=68$.